# How to delay event propagation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, event-propagation

I want to display a note after the user submits a form but before he leaves the page.

Currently I'm using this (reduced example code):

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    $('.note').show();

    setTimeout(function() {                 
        $('form').unbind().submit();
    }, 2000);

    return false;
});
```

This works but doesn't seem to be nice. Is there any other way, like a function `$.delayPropagation(2000);`?

PS: The note covers the whole screen, so the user won't be able to submit again during this time.

Comment: "`doesn't seem to be nice`" is not a good technical description of the problem. Try again? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie True that. It works, but it seems wrong to me doing it that way. It looks like some sort of "working around the problem" and a dirty solution.

Comment: It's okay. You will have to use setTimeout anyway.

Comment: That is an appropriate way to do it. You must `return false` immediately to avoid blocking the browser.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie OK, thanks guys. If this is OK I'll stick to it.

Comment: Leave it.. keep the 5 points :)

Comment: Added some extra notes to my comment as an answer for you.

Comment: makes no sense to delay sending form, user could close window during that time. Why not show note after the form is sibmitted

Comment: @charlietfl: Or better yet, submit the form via Ajax. Then wait. Otherwise the submit will throw the page away :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie whatever way, the main point is to get the data processed first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an appropriate way to delay the operation.

You may actually want to unbind the event first to stop multiple calls (you currently have a 2 second window in which they could submit again).

As a standard practice, you should only run your jQuery selectors once (use a temp var to hold the result). `$` prefixes are also another standard for naming jQuery variables. This now means the code below would support multiple forms on a page separately.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $('.note').show();
    $form.unbind()
    setTimeout(function() {                 
        $form.submit();
    }, 2000);

    return false;
});
```

You must `return false` immediately to avoid blocking the browser.

Notes:

- *An alternative would be to use `Ajax` for the form post, then have the delay, then goto a new page*
- `setTimeout` is the most [ubiquitous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ubiquitous) way to delay code from executing.

*Note: I just wanted to use the term `ubiquitous` in a post :)*

Comment: +1 Thanks for your effort. I now unbind directly as you suggested.

Comment: I always store selectors in variables - I just wanted to make the example code as easy as possible to read. :)

Comment: the above code works! but i dont understand why its not gone in infinite loop?
when we try to submit the form after 2 sec in setTimeout() method, it should call the same submit handler and return false immediately and set the timer again...

Comment: @KaleemNalband As the page will be refreshed by the `submit()`, it does not matter if we generate a second event 2 seconds later. The page has gone. From memory, a direct `form.submit()` may not generate the jQuery event.